# Only copy essential files from old Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, migration

I am taking over the management of a Magento site from developers who made a mess.

I have a clean install of Magento, and would like to only copy the necessary files from the previous installation.
Which folders should I synchronise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud do a basic scan of the enabled theme app/design/frontend/
to make sure all the code is clean.  Move this across and enable it without porting any extensions this way you can see which of the modules are actually used by the theme.

Once you have this you can port across the app/code// files across one by one checking the frontend as you go.

Comment: How would I see which of the modules are actually used by the theme?

Comment: Well you would know pretty quick on the frontend if the page breaks half way through the page or if blocks are missing. This is the lazy way so to speak otherwise go through the theme files ones by one and see which blocks are being called manually and through the layout files to see which layout files are directly related to modules

Comment: Regarding the database, should I just grab all, or can I select certain tables?

Comment: Well is it a clean installation? i mean is there any reported compramises? if not copy the entire database is fine, just debloat it by truncating the log tables to bring down the size.

Comment: It seems the layout also look for files in the skin folder. Could I clean that up? Also so Magento can merge js and css files.

Comment: It wouldnt harm as legacy sites have allot of old js files being loaded that are not longer used so knowing which ones are being used is deffinatly a good idea